# How to access as_secs in SystemTime? "no method named `as_secs` found for enum Result"

Tags: rust, systemtime

I'm using [`std::time::SystemTime`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html). My goal is to make a struct with a field called `timestamp` and store the time in seconds.

I saw this example which works correctly:

```rust
use std::time::SystemTime;

match SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH) {
    Ok(n) => println!("1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC was {} seconds ago!", n.as_secs()),
    Err(_) => panic!("SystemTime before UNIX EPOCH!"),
}
```

When I try this code I get an error:

```
use std::time::SystemTime;

let n = SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH);
println!("{}", n.as_secs());
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `as_secs` found for enum `std::result::Result<std::time::Duration, std::time::SystemTimeError>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:5:22
  |
5 |     println!("{}", n.as_secs());
  |                      ^^^^^^^ method not found in `std::result::Result<std::time::Duration, std::time::SystemTimeError>`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to extract the result from `std::result::Result`. [Error handling introduction](https://stevedonovan.github.io/rust-gentle-intro/6-error-handling.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the error:

```
no method named `...` found for type `Result<...>`
```

So, we look at [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html):

> `Result` is a type that represents either success ([`Ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Ok)) or faliure ([`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err))
>
> See the [`std::result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/index.html) module for documentation details.

So, we know that [`SystemTime::duration_since(&self, _)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html#method.duration_since) returns a `Result`, meaning it could possibly have failed. Reading the docs:

> Returns an [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err) if `earlier` is later than `self`, and the error contains how far from `self` the time is.

So, we just have to [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap), [`expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect), or match on it to get the possibility of an error out:

```rust
use std::time::SystemTime;

// Unwrapping
let n = SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH)
    .unwrap(); // Will panic if it is not `Ok`.

// Expecting
let n = SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH)
    .expect("Invalid time comparison"); // Will panic with error message
        // if it is not `Ok`.

// Matching
let n = SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH);
match n {
    Ok(x) => { /* Use x */ },
    Err(e) => { /* Process Error e */ },
}

// Fallibly Destructuring:
let n = SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH);
if let Ok(x) = n {
    /* Use x */
} else {
    /* There was an error. */
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example using `unwrap` and `expect` on the question context?

Comment: @user, I've edited my answer to include examples.